# Jquery error on the production server

Tags: 7, javascript

We have a weird bug with the Linked module.

We installed Linkit on a Drupal 7 website on the WISYWIG with TinyMCE. On environments local and staging, it works perfectly but in the production environment on a different server, the modal of linkit is empty and we have the error javascript:

```
TypeError: $(...).once is not a function
Drupal.behaviors.panopolyImagesModule.attach()
 jquery.js:5
Drupal.attachBehaviors/<()
 drupal.js:76
.each()
 jquery.js:654
Drupal.attachBehaviors()
 drupal.js:74
Drupal.ajax.prototype.commands.insert()
 ajax.js:570
Drupal.ajax.prototype.success()
 ajax.js:428
Drupal.linkit.getDashboard/Drupal.ajax["linkit-modal"].options.success()
 linkit.js:117
jQuery.Callbacks/fire()
 jquery.js:1075
jQuery.Callbacks/self.fireWith()
 jquery.js:1193
done()
 jquery.js:7538
.send/callback()
 jquery.js:8324
```

The version on JQuery in 1.7.2 on all environments.

I tried to reproduce the bug in local, same code, same database, no problem. I try to execute the javascript step by step, I found the last line on linkit js before the exception is:

```
Drupal.ajax['linkit-modal'].success(response, status);
```

in the file linkit.js line 117.

Too many things happen in library js in Drupal core, I missed the line which launch the exception.

The markup of the modal is limited to:

```
<div style="width: auto; max-height: none; height: auto; min-height: 0px;" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" id="linkit-modal"></div>
```

Additionnally, I have this html behind the modal:

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1px; height: 362px;" id="freeze-height"></div>
```

If I understand well, drupal.js add this block during the generation of element to prevent upwards scrolling. The function is call by ajax.js line 424, in the function `Drupal.ajax.prototype.success` but the execute bug before (or during) the UnfreezeHeight, line 441 of ajax.js, so the block isn't remove.

So, if I understand well, I could search in this part of code, but I don't understand very well the javascript drupal engine so I don't know if I'm on a good track.

I verify the configuration server, I see nothing which could influence the behavior but maybe I missed something.

The linkit module is installed with the profile of OpenAtrium, I look issue on the Linkit Project, OpenAtrium and Panopoly, but I find nothing which could help me :-/

Comment: The problem appears to be that the jQuery `once()` plugin can't be found.. It's a bug in a different module, but looking at https://www.drupal.org/node/1996308 it suggests it could be because jQuery is being loaded more than once on the page? A little more info here could be useful too - for example, is this a Drupal 7 or Drupal 8 site? If it's related to the above, have you checked that the jQuery version is the same in both production and local environments? (You can check it with `jQuery().jquery` in the browser console).

Comment: It's a Drupal 7 site.
The version of javascript is 1.7.2 on all environments. We have the same code and fix configuration in features, the only differences is the minify on js enabled in production.